# C++ Program that adds positive odd numbers from keyboard, ignores even and stops when negative number or zero are entered - sum odd numbers

Tags: while-loop, character, decimal

So technically I have done what the assignment says because this works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{


        int number = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        cout << "Please enter an odd positive integer: " << endl;
        cout << "This program will end if number is <= 0 or decimal" << endl;
        
        
        cin >> number;
    
        while (number > 0)
        {
            if (number % 2 != 0)
                sum = sum + number;
            else
                cout << "That number was even - please enter odd number \n";
            
            
        
            cin >> number;
        }
        cout << "Sum of odd numbers = " << sum << endl;
        
        return 0;
}
```

However - it dawned on me that the program quits when someone enters a double or enters a character, rather than just warning that this will happen - I would love to write this in. I have tried using else if statements and I am not getting the desired results.  I am not asking for someone to solve this for me *per se* but if I could just get sent in the right direction. We are currently working on while and for loops and increments (which don't seem to apply here at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you'd have to change your `number` variable to a `string` to take in "anything", deal with garbage input, and finally convert it to an `int` if it fit your requirements. This usually isn't too hard, but can get tricky at times. Google is usually your friend here. It's bee a while since I did C++, so I'd have to consult it, too, to get things correct.

And when you say "double", is that the number is 2 digits or is too long to be an `int`? That little bit of ambiguity is throwing me off. If it's just too big a number being an actual `double` datatype, the `string` should help with that, as would a problem a 2 digit number.

And for an increment being useful, you could use `sum += number;`, depending on your version of C++. Older versions don't allow that, but newer versions do. I'd be surprised of a gcc or other compiler wasn't new enough to have it available, at this point.

Comment: I didn't even think about making it a string, good point!  Originally I was only trying to deal with integers - then I had an aha about letters, because I just know, even though it wasn't asked, it will totally come up. Ha ha. I mean double - more like, I mean float. I am talking about decimals. Obviously decimals go with the exit command because of the '.' - I definitely don't want anyone to do it for me, I NEED to understand it, I just got caught in a lil bit of an infinity loop myself - tee hee.

Comment: @CandiceMcDonald, yep, it's easy to get stuck in a rut and even just go around in circles thinking the same "solutions" repeatedly that don't work. This is why having a 2nd set of eyes is good. It's why some devs have a rubber duck on their desk, to explain the code to, which often ends up explaining to themselves why it's not working. No, seriously. I'm not even joking. https://medium.com/@katiebrouwers/why-rubber-ducking-is-one-of-your-greatest-resources-as-a-developer-99ac0ee5b70a